# How to get useEffect to not re-render infinitely

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to render this CardsContainerCopy component after making an AJAX call with Redux-thunk.

If I leave the dependencies array in useEffect empty, the  component doesn't render at all.

If I add `cartItems` to the dependencies array, the  components will render but the `fetchItems` function keeps being called infinitely.

Code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import SingleCard from "./SingleCard";
import { createServer } from "miragejs";
import axios from "axios";
import itemsData from "../../config/ItemsData";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectCartItems } from "./shopSlice";

let server = createServer();
server.get("/api/food", itemsData);

const fetchItems = async (dispatch) => {
  const itemsData = await axios.get("/api/food");
  dispatch({ type: "shop/fetchedItems", payload: itemsData.data });
};

const CardsContainerCopy = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cartItems = useSelector(selectCartItems);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchItems);
    setItems(cartItems);
  }, [cartItems]);

  return (
    <>
      {items?.map((item, i) => {
        return <SingleCard props={item} key={i} />;
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default CardsContainerCopy;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your useEffect function does create an infinite loop, as you're listening to cartItems changes which triggers dispatch again. To avoid infinite re render you can do something like this:

```
const CardsContainerCopy = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cartItems = useSelector(selectCartItems);


  useEffect(()=>{
     dispatch(fetchItems);
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
     setItems(cartItems);
  }, [cartItems]);

  return (
    <>
      {items?.map((item, i) => {
        return <SingleCard props={item} key={i} />;
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s that `cartItems` in `useEffect`’s dependencies who’s causing the infinite calls, as in the same `useEffect`, you are updating it.

You could do so, in two steps:

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(fetchItems);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  setItems(cartItems);
}, [cartItems]);
```

Comment: Hi @yousoumar. I tried doing that but now the `<SingleCard/>` component does not render at all. I suppose this is because the `setItems` function is being called once on loading of the parent component, but the state is still [] (ie. the `dispatch` function has not updated the state yet).

Comment: Hi ! Try with my just updated response.